# NullPointerExeption при работе с CameraApp

Tags: android, android-camera

При попытке сделать фото в `onActivityRsult` получаю `NullPointerExaption` когда достаю данные из интента, при этом фото сохраняется но мне выдает сообщение что произошла ошибка, получается что `Intent data == null`. Делаю по туториалу с офф.сайта, не могу понять где ошибся.

```
 private void callCameraApp(){
        Uri fileUri;
        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFileUri(CameraHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

        Log.e(TAG, "fileUri: " + fileUri);
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

 private void extractCaptureImage(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Intent data: " + data);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                        data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
            Toast.makeText(this, "User cancelled the image capture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Логи:

```
Log.e(TAG, "Intent data boolean: " + (data == null)); //true
Log.e(TAG, "Intent data object: " + data); //null
```

Comment: Под дебагом просмотрите вашу data. Тут надо точно знать null она или нет

Comment: Просто возможно в дату передается битмапка

Comment: я добавил под вопрос результаты

Comment: Вы не используете Camera API

Comment: @metalurgus исправил - CameraApp, знаете в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение проблемы:**

Причина по которой в Intent ничего не возвращается  в этой строчке         `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)`. Указав параметр `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` и файл в который нужно сохранить фото - фото сохраняется автоматически и соответственно ничего не возвращается, если строчку `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)` - закоментировать, то в Intent'е будет возвращаться Bitmap и его нужно будет сохранять вручную.